# Use Polymorphic Associations with Default Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, associations, polymorphic-associations

I am contributing one of the ruby on rails application over GitHub where I faced the following scenario:

I am having following models which I want to convert to make polymorphic:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :project
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I made following changes to make it polymorphic:

Perform database change to removed team_id, project_id and added commentable_id and commentable_type to comments table.

Modifications in models as described within rails guides:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy
end
```

While I use it with default scope, It doesn't allow me to use with default scope and gives error in below line in Project Model:

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy
```

I am getting following error on my browser:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hey I had a similar thing happen to me , I opened an issue on Rails github ... Let's see if we can get any input on this . https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25288

Answer (score 3):

OK so this is how it should be done, scope is second argument and options hash is after

```
has_many :comments, -> { order('created_at DESC') } ,{as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy}
```

Check out the docs
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1359

"You can pass a **second** argument +scope+ as a callable"

I did the exact same mistake as you, confusing isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Just put "dependent: :destroy" BEFORE the lambda function.

This is a very boring syntax stuff in ruby. You don't need to put brackets `{}` to declare hash in parameters unless you declare more than one hash.

Your current code would works if you write

```
  has_many :comments, { as: :commentable }, -> { ... }, { dependent: :destroy }
```

Because both key/value pairs are not in the same hash, ruby fail to interpret the line.

Instead, just moving `dependent: :destroy` after `as: :commentable` will tell ruby on handle the two key/value pair in the same hash.

```
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

Happy Coding,

Yacine.

Comment: Hi @Yacine, Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. After modifying the code, I am getting same error. I updated the question.